# How do you name a component that both encrypts and decrypts depending on method you use?

Tags: class, encryption

I would like to give a good name to class that will contain both methods for encryption and
decryption using the same alghoritm.
Does anyone have an idea for naming seemingly opposing expressions under one term?

I found a name for class that encodes and decodes a string of characters, ie. "codec" (COder-DECoder).
I dont want to use the codec term for encryption operations if I already used it for character encoding.

Methods will be something like:

```
NameOfTheClass.Encrypt(string plainText);
NameOfTheClass.Decrypt(string cipherText);
```

Comment: Cryptographer for class? Cryptographic for interface? From a documentation perspective, I think the names of your methods are more important than the name of the class

Comment: Try naming it with the algo's name. (This is not a good question for this site, naming conventions are completely subjective.)

Comment: Cryptographer sounds good. Thanks!
I was wondering if as programmers with experience you have any naming rules that could be applied for naming something that contains opposing methods.

Comment: Naming it with algo's name would be hard. I have to write it in non-english name, and in my language it's pretty long.

Comment: Voted to migrate to http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 5):

Such classes are usually named after the cipher they implement. If you have a base class with virtual methods that will be implemented by several different cipher classes, that class usually has a name like `BlockCipher` or something, depending on exactly what you are doing with it.

Answer (score 2):

Is it an absolute logical requirement that encryption and decryption be the same operation? If not, I'd have both Encrypt and Decrypt methods, since they are different logical operations. If so, you can either use 'Crypt' or something that better describes the algorithm you're using or the reason you're using it.

Comment: Well, in Vernam Cipher they kind of are. That's not the point. I'd like to use the separate method names, but containt them in one common class.